# scala# extending loan pattern with type parameter: issue

Tags: scala

Trying to extend loan pattern with type parameter and getting next error.
Looks like just just a syntax error.
I do suspect that this is a currying limitation? and return type must be provided in some way in my case.
Thanks!

```
      import java.io._

     //def withPrintWriter(file: File)( op: PrintWriter => Unit) {      
     def withPrintWriter[T: Numeric](file: File)(implicit count: Numeric[T])( op: PrintWriter => Unit) {        
    import count._
    val writer = new PrintWriter(file)      
    try {           
        for(x <- 0 to count.toInt() )
        {                           
            op(writer)
        }
    } finally {
        writer.close()
    }
}


val file = new File("date.txt")

withPrintWriter[Int]( file )( 5 ){
//withPrintWriter( file ){
    writer => writer.println( new java.util.Date )  
}
```

Error:
        c:\Sources\scala\main.scala:101: error: '=' expected but '(' found.
        def withPrintWriter[T: Numeric](file: File)(implicit count: Numeric[T])(
             op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
                                                                               ^
           c:\Sources\scala\main.scala:115: error: illegal start of simple expression
        val file = new File("date.txt")
^

Comment: The parameter list with `implicit` must be the last one, and using `T : Numeric` there is no need for the implicit param. Either `def withPrintWriter[T](file: File)(op: PrintWriter => Unit)(implicit count: Numeric[T]): Unit` or `def withPrintWriter[T : Numeric](file: File)(op: PrintWriter => Unit): Unit` (using `val count = implicitly[Numeric[T]]` in the fun body.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've manage to resolve function signature issue: withPrintWriter[T: Numeric](file: File)( op: PrintWriter => Unit)(implicit count: T) : Unit   ; but getting issue when calling this function:                           val file = new File("date.txt")
 val count : Int = 5 
 withPrintWriter[Int]( file )( writer => writer.println( new java.util.Date ) ) ( count )   Error: Not enough arguments provided! :(

Comment: `implicit count: T` as no sense there

Comment: got it! its work perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like have to post the as answer to my question :)
implicit  was not required to use in the original code! Looks simple ...

```
    def withPrintWriter[T: Numeric](file: File)(count: T)( op: PrintWriter => Unit) {       
    val writer = new PrintWriter(file)      
    try {           
        for(x <- 0 to count.asInstanceOf[Int] )
        {                           
            op(writer)
        }
    } finally {
        writer.close()
    }
}


val file = new File("date.txt")
val count : Int = 5 

withPrintWriter[Int]{ file }{ count }    
{ 
    writer => writer.println( new java.util.Date ) 
}
```

Comment: The `asInstanceOf[T]` is unsafe and make the view bound `: Numeric` useless. Better doing `val limit = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toInt(count); (0 to limit).foreach { _ => op(writer) }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip,  I didn't know that, what this unsafey could lead to? I would suspect to crash type conversion not possible?

Comment: `isInstanceOf` is unsafe in itself

Answer (score 0):

From just a quick glance, it looks like your method def is missing an `=` before the body (brackets)...eg `def foo(a: Int): Int = { ... }`

Comment: Well, apparently = is not required as I can see. Next function signature works fine: def withPrintWriter[T: Numeric](file: File)( op: PrintWriter => Unit)(count: T)  {

Comment: `=` is not required because `def foo() {` automatically define the return type to `Unit` (is the same as `def foo(): Unit = {`)

Comment: Right, my bad...I wasn't paying attention to the fact that this was returning Unit; my apologies if this was misleading!